# Jmeter 2.9 in distributed testing mode - cannot see response data in View Results Tree

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, jmeter

I have jmeter-client on my local Windows-based machine and jmeter-server on Ubuntu-based machine in Amazon AWS.

It works well. I can generate load and get results in csv-files on my local machine.
But I have a little problem.
When I use it, I can`t see the response data from server in csv files and in View Result Tree.
But I see the response code  - it's 200 OK, see latency, response time etc.

When I try to test it from my local machine, without jmeter-server, it looks good, and I can see the response data.

Can anybody please help me?

Comment: Any feedback on this ?

Answer (score 1):

Since JMeter 2.9:

> Distributed testing now uses MODE_STRIPPED_BATCH, which returns samples in batch mode (every 100 samples or every minute by default). Note also that MODE_STRIPPED_BATCH strips response data from SampleResult, so if you need it change to another mode (mode property in jmeter.properties)

Usually full responses are not useful during load test and impact negatively performances of JMeter, so be sure you really need them

Answer (score 0):

I have executed tests in similar environment but on amazon AWS. Providing Hostname for both JMeter client and server solved the problem. This is explained on Apache JMeter user manual page but with different intention under [Tips section](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html).

You can start JMeter server with option `-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=<ip_address>` on command line and same required for client.